# Count amount of points for XY options (in poll) where options dont have equal amount of points

Tags: php, math

I have a code where I want to avoid using a for/each loop to count the amount of points options in poll have together. Reason is, every option has different ammount of points and I want to get number of votes by counting options and points they have together and then dividing total points (votes) by those points...

I have a list of options where every option has a different amount of points. I think this is easier to understand:

- Option 1 = 7 points
- Option 2 = 6 points
- Option 3 = 5 points
- Option 4 = 4 points
- Option 5 = 3 points
- Option 6 = 2 points
- Option 7 = 1 point

Is there some easy math way of getting to number of points (in this case **28**) without using:

```
$options = array("lala", "lalala", "flflf", "qddwq", "adslalsd", "wqdqowdq", "acaca");
$points = 0; $i = 1;
foreach($options as $option){
    $points = $points + $i;
    $i++;
}
echo $points;
```

Or

```
$points = 0;
$options_num = 7;

for ($i=1; $i <= $options_num; $i++){
      $points = $points + $i;
}
echo $points;
```

I just want to make as small load on the server as possible, mainly when users won't be limited with amount of options they can insert and I am sure there has to be some simple math I can use, but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: Eight minus option number?  I don't see where you're getting 28 from.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 28

Comment: There's 8 options; you need a loop.  No getting around it.  Don't try to optimize something before you understand whether or not it is actually causing a performance problem.

Comment: But I already mentioned that I am not limiting my users in amount of options, so there can be 100 or even more options. And then imagine thousands of users looking at results with hundreds options. I think there has to be some way of calculationg it without loops.

Comment: Are the options in a database?  You can do a GROUP BY/SUM query if they are.

Comment: The optiosn have alway same amount of points. If there are 10 options, then first one has 10 points and last one has 1 point. If there is 100 options, first one has 100 points and last one 1 point etc. etc. Options are saved as serialized array in database, so no way of using group by/sum.

Comment: `(n * (n + 1)) / 2` ... See [Triangular Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Aaaand thats what I exactly wanted. I just had a complete brain fart and could not figure this out. Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum

```
7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 28
```

Corresponds to a [Triangular Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) of the form

```
(n * (n + 1)) / 2
```

i.e. `(7 * (7 + 1) / 2` = 28.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to tell you that in your example you have ``7 * 1`` instead of ``7 + 1``. I wanted to edit it myself, but edits have to be longer than 6 characters.